# Insert a value into a reversed ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to insert a value given by the user into an ArrayList in Java. The values should be in descending order so that if the user provides e.g. *6, 2, 19* the output should be *19, 6, 2*. My idea was to insert the first element and then all other inputs would be compared to the other elements and inserted accordingly.

getScore() receives a value from another class and rank() places one value at a time.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> sortedInts = new ArrayList<>();

private String rank() {
    if(sortedInts.isEmpty()){
        sortedInts.add(0, getScore());
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= sortedInts.size(); i++) {
            if(getScore() >= sortedInts.get(i) && getScore() <= sortedInts.get(i+1))
                sortedInts.add(i, getScore());
        }
    }
    int position = sortedInts.indexOf(getScore());
    if(position % 10 == 0) {
        if(position == 0)
            return "1st";
        else
            return position + "st";
    }
    else if(position % 10 == 1){
        if(position == 1)
            return "2nd";
        else
            return position + "nd";
    }
    else if(position % 10 == 2) {
        if(position == 2)
            return "3rd";
        else
            return position + "rd";
    }
    else
        return position + "th";
}
```

Comment: why you have to do it manually? Just add number in the arrayList then sort it Collections.sort(arraylist, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: You can use `SortedSet` instead, and use `Collections.reverseOrder();`

Comment: Collections.reverse(list) will reverse the list

Comment: @mangusta - yeah, just saw it and deleted my comment and then I saw yours

Comment: and by the way, if `getScore()` returns a new value on each call, the code is incorrect - he calls it over and over again instead of assigning the returned value once. not clear what's his question though

Comment: *Curious:* Position 0 is "1st", 1 is "2nd", 2 is "3rd", 3 is **"3th"**, ..., 9 is **"9th"**, 10 is **"10st"**, 11 is **"11nd"**, 12 is **"12rd"**, ..., 20 is **"20st"**, 21 is **"21nd"**, ... --- I think you need to re-check your logic there.

Comment: @SagarAhuja Maybe the data can contain duplicate values. If so then he/she can't use sets

Comment: @priyanka Yes, in that case, he/she can use a list. and then sort it in reverse order.

Comment: Ohh, I am so grateful for the tips and comments. I will surely work on that and and eventually improve :).